# Turning angles in Radio and Telephone

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization, plane-wave

Radio waves and microwaves are usually plane polarised. This is why you can sometimes get a better signal if you turn a radio or telephone through different angles.Okay what happens when we turn a radio or telephone through different angle?

Comment: You better align the (usually linear) antenna with the signal of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've mentioned, radio waves are polarized.

If, for example, we take a simple dipole transmitting antenna, electric field it generates in all directions will be polarized such that it always lies in the plane of the dipole.

The direction and relative magnitude of the dipole's electric field, along any particular line, at a substantial distance from the antenna (far field), is described by its radiation pattern, which looks like a donut. A simplified example of its cross-section is shown on the diagram below.

[image]

Here, electric field vectors, $E_1$ and $E_2$, lie in the plane of the dipole antenna (the vertical line in the middle of the diagram), but have different directions (normal to the direction of wave propagation vectors $d_1$ and $d_2$) and different magnitudes (proportional to the length of $d_1$ and $d_2$).

Due to the reciprocity of antennas, the receiving pattern of a dipole is identical to its transmitting or radiation pattern.

So, if the dipole on the diagram was a receiving antenna and the electric field of the incoming radio signal was in its plane, such antenna would be more sensitive to the signal coming from the direction $d_1$ than to the signal coming from the direction $d_2$.

If the transmitted electric field was normal to the dipole plane (going through the diagram), the theoretical sensitivity of the receiving antenna to such signal would be zero, regardless of the wave propagation direction.

If the transmitted electric field was at some intermediate angle relative to the dipole plane, the sensitivity would be proportional to the cosine of that angle.

Although this is a grossly simplified picture, based on a particular type of antenna, it illustrates why the reception of a radio or a cell phone is so sensitive to the angle of the antenna relative to the direction of the field (polarization) of the incoming signal.

In reality, due to various obstacles, reflections, interference, etc. the strength of a radio signal may vary widely from point to point, so, in addition to the orientation of the receiving antenna, the quality of reception could be significantly affected by its exact location.

Comment: I want to add, that the induced magnetic field has a well definded direction too and this direction depends from the accelerated charges. For electrons (and antiprotons) it has to be opposite to the direction for protons and positrons. this has to do with their spins.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you are, it may make reception only slightly better or slightly worse. Here's why:

although cell phone broadcasts are vertically polarized to start with, the sense of polarization gets lost during reflections off of objects along the signal's direction of propagation, so that after some distance from the cell tower the signal usually contains a mix of polarization states. this means your reception is not going to be too strongly affected by the orientation of the antenna inside the phone. Note also that the design of the antenna inside the phone is deliberately chosen so as to be relatively insensitive to polarization effects.